# Vector field on a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the equation:
$$\mathbf{F}(x_1,...,x_n)=\mathbf{0}$$

I know that a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ restricts on a vector field on the submanifold iff it annihilates the components of $\mathbf{F}$. Basically there is a surjection

$$\Pi : \text{Ann}_{\text{Der}(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n))}(F_1,...,F_{n-k})\to \text{Der}(C^{\infty}(M))$$

that simply restricts the vector field to the submanifold. I understand what "restricting" to the submanifold means if we see vector field in the intuitive manner, but I fail to understand how a derivation of the algebra $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ restricts to a derivation of the algebra $C^{\infty}(M)$. Who is $\Pi(X)$ as a derivation?

Comment: The vector field $X$ on $M$ corresponds to the derivation $(Xf)(p) = df(p)X(p)$ on $C^{\infty}(M)$. If $f$ is defined on $M$, and $X$ is instead a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for $X$ to restrict to a vector field on $C^{\infty}(M)$, we need $X(p) \in T_pM$ for all $p \in M$, and we have $(\Pi(X)f)(p) = df(p)X(p)$.